# Images in front matter for Gatsby.js

Tags: markdown, gatsby

I've been struggling with this:

My front matter looks like:

```
---
path: '/path-to/'
title: 'Title of Post'
indexImage: './img.jpg'
---
```

with my image in the same folder as my `index.md` file.

In my `templates/post.js` file, I have the following line:

```
<img src={ post.frontmatter.indexImage }></img>
```

thinking this would pull in the source listed in the front matter. My post.js query is:

```
export const postQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPostByPath($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        path
        title
        indexImage
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Below is the error message:

```
GraphQL Error Field "indexImage" of type "File" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean "indexImage { ... }"?
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't working? I'm still new to Gatsby, so it may be an issue that is over my head. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

> must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean "indexImage { ... }

Is the key part of the error.

Anytime you see "subfields" and a field (like `indexImage`) with `{ ... }` it means that this is an "object" type not a "scalar" (e.g. string, number, float, etc.) type.

So your query should look something like:

```
query BlogPostByPath($path: String!) {
  markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
    html
    frontmatter {
      path
      title
      indexImage {
        childImageSharp {
          resolutions(width: 400) {
            width
            height
            src
            srcSet
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This example site documents how to use the image processing queries https://image-processing.gatsbyjs.org/

Comment: Thank you for your response! Now I'm getting this error: `GraphQL Error Unknown field resolutions on type File`. I have `gatsby-transformer-sharp` and `gatsby-plugin-sharp` added but alas.

Comment: Oops, I got the query wrong. Fixed now. BTW, have you learned how to use GraphiQL yet? It makes it easy to explore the schema for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Invalidate the build cache by deleting the `.cache` folder.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I deleted the `.cache` folder and ran `gatsby develop` again and ran into the same issue. Any other thoughts? Was there something wrong in the `.cache` folder?

Comment: Then try putting double quotes around the frontmatter values. And delete the cache every time until you get this thing resolved. I know the cache plays a role in compiling GraphQL types. This could be a bug. Once deleted the cache the type error disappeared.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part - I did have double quotes around the frontmatter values in my code - I just forgot to add them when I created this post and question.

Comment: I am currently using v1.7.15 of the gatsby-transformer-remark package, what's yours?

Comment: I am using the same version.

Answer (score 0):

If image was converted to File type you want to use publicUrl instead of trying to use image directly:

```
      frontmatter {
        path
        title
        indexImage {
          publicUrl
        }
      }
```

and than in code:

```
<img src={ post.frontmatter.indexImage.publicUrl } />
```